# Zend - Action for sub-directories

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to create an action for the URL `http://<domain>/admincp/prank/scripts/approved`

My directory structure is as follows:

[image]

In PrankController.php I have

```
public function scriptsAction() {
    var_dump("script");
}

public function approvedAction() {
    var_dump("approved");
}
```

When I go to my page, I get "script", instead of "approved". How do I react to the last part of the URL, the `/approved` part?

Answer (score 0):

In this url `http://<domain>/admincp/prank/scripts/approved` the part approved is not actually taken care of your controller. it is taken care of as a variable due to missing controller of that part of the directory.

```
$post = $this->_request->getParams();
```

and it would return like this `$post['approved']="";`
if you try this in yopur current controller, this is what you will see. The reason is because that word approved is received as a variable thr url.
How can you Fix it?
      you need a controller class name as `adminpcb_scriptsController` and in this controller class place your `approvedAction` as public function.
      You would probably need the create a controller, helper and view folder in scripts folder(i am not sure about that part 100%)